# How does blocked vent switch work?

Tags: switch, vent

A `blocked vent switch` is a device mounted to a burner vent hood that includes a sensor detecting that the vent is blocked, then switched the gas supply off if tripped. My question is, how does this small device know that the vent is blocked? How is the sensing done?

[image]

Comment: Would guess pressure change.  Block should cause pressure to increase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These switches are pressure actuated and a manually reset.  If it reset itself when the pressure dropped, the switch would just turn on and off repeatedly  as the boiler/furnace cycled.  Between the wires there is a little part that you push in to reset the switch.

Other gas appliances like modern HVAC systems also have pressure switches to make sure there is enough air flow so that the unit doesn't overheat, and the exhaust fumes are properly vented.

There are also thermal switches that look very similar to this, but they tend to be auto-resetting rather than requiring a button push.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely — there again not seeing the application — A “blocked vent” would cause heat to build up in the furnace vent and the heat would move down into the furnace where a temperature actuated switch ( blocked vent switch) Would be locate and being temperature actuated switch would “open” causing the gas valve circuit to be incomplete and the gas valve would “close” under it’s own spring pressure shutting off the gas flow
—- The gas valve requires power to stay open against its own spring pressure as a safety or fail safe device —

Comment: This looks like speculation, especially since the question has already been answered authoritatively with different information. If you have sources on this "heat moving down...temperature actuated switch" you should [edit] them into your answer to support this. We don't do speculation here. Take the [tour] to find out more about expectations of Questions and Answers and supporting information.